# How to Avoid Fetching Data Twice When Using React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I'm trying to fetch a set of questions from a Firestore database, and then store them in a local array for use later on in a quiz. As I'm working to fetch the data, it's running asynchronously. I've dealt with this before, and the solution was a `useEffect()` hook and conditionally rendering component.

My code currently looks like this:

```
var questions = [];
var collection = useRef('Planning');
var [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);  

useEffect(() => {
        if (props.track === 'Testing & Deployment') {
            collection.current = 'Test_Deploy';
        } else {
            collection.current = props.track;
        }

        if(questions.length !== 0){
            setLoading(false)
        } else {
            var questionSet = db.collection('Quizzes').doc(collection.current).collection('Questions')

            questionSet.withConverter(questionConverter).get().then(function(response) {
                    response.forEach(document => {
                        var question = document.data();
                        // running asynch - need to address
                        console.log('Question in')
                        questions.push(question)
                    })
            })
            setLoading(false)
        }

    }, [props.track, questions])}
```

Depending on where `setLoading()` is, the component either won't re-render at all, or will double fetch the data from Firestore. I've tried playing around  with `useCallback()` to no avail, and have also seen that this might be an issue with React `StrictMode`.

Any advice on how to fix my code in order to re-render the page after fetching all of the questions, without double fetching them?

Comment: FYI, `questions` will be reset back to empty array `[]` each render cycle. It should be part of your component state. Is your question really about fetching data, once, on component mount?

Comment: Yeah, that's likely at the heart of the issue. I attempted to utilize a class component before this, but found that it was difficult to update a state array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fetch data once on component mount you can specify an empty dependency array. I also suggest moving the `questions` object into local component state. Since the state is updated in a loop you should use a functional state update to add each new question to the array.

```
const [questions, setQuestions] = useState([]);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

useEffect(() => {
  const questionSet = db
    .collection("Quizzes")
    .doc(collection.current)
    .collection("Questions");

  questionSet
    .withConverter(questionConverter)
    .get()
    .then(function (response) {
      response.forEach((document) => {
        const question = document.data();
        setQuestions(questions => [...questions, question]);
      });
    });

  setLoading(false);
}, []);
```

If the linter complains about missing dependencies then you need to either add them and place the appropriate conditional check on the data fetch, or add a comment to ignore/disable the linter for the line with the dependency array, `// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`.

Comment: Exactly what I needed to do. Thank you Drew!

Answer (score 0):

It will rerender again when the props change or update including `props.track` and `questions` everytime when you push item into it. So if you want to get rid of it rerender then just remove from `useEffect` like

```
useEffect(() => {
        .......

}, [loading])} // remove from here and add `loading` here just
```

Comment: Putting just loading in the brackets will still raise a warning that dependencies are missing. I'm afraid I'm misunderstanding your correction.